# Mouse if offset in Citrix application

Tags: windows-7, mouse, resolution, citrix, citrix-receiver

I am using Citrix Receiver from my Windows 7 (yeah, I know...) PC to access certain applications, one being Acrobat Standard. I also have access to another app in Citrix, which has the same problem.
EDIT: I have since upgraded my PC to Windows 10 and I am still having the same issue.

The issue is that the mouse is offset by about 20x20 pixels.

In the picture below, in order to select "Open" under "File", my mouse has to be right above the next menu item "Organizer"

[image: Mouse offset]

App shortcut Properties

- Shortcut tab

  - Target type: `Application`
  - Target location: `SelfServicePlugin`
  - Target: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\SelfService.exe" -launch -reg "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\portal-12cd4d5@@Acrobat Standard"`
  - Start in: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin"`
  - Shortkut key: `None`
  - Run: `Minimized`
  - Comment: `Adobe Acrobat 9 Standard`
- Compatibility tab

  - Settings: `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings`

**Citrix version**: `4.11.0.17061`
**Server version**: `Windows Server 2003  Standard Edition`

**PC screen resolution**: `1920x1200` ("recommended")
[image: Screen resolution]

**PC Display settings:** `100%`
[image: Display settings]

I tried each of the "**High DPI**" settings in Citrix Receiver
Right click on Citrix Receiver > Advanced Preferences > High DPI
[image: High DPI]

Comment: So, basically you are trying to deal with 4 products that are completely out of support, Win7, Server2003, Citrix Receiver and Acrobat 9 ;) What happens if you let it scale? & bear in mind Win 2003 probably has no idea what a HiDPI screen is.

Comment: Also, if you change off the recommended resolution to 1920x1080, I wonder the the mouse would work then. It may look funky, but just to test.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yeah unfortunately, not much I can do about that. I have tried all 3 options for the "Scale the session for high resolution" and none help.